# Jackson ClassCastException Custom Object Mapper

Tags: java, json, generics, jersey, jackson

I use a Custom Object Mapper to Serialize/Deserialize a Json in Java Object.
I also register the Custom Object Mapper on the Jax-RS Application Interface (Jersey).

```
public class AppConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
public AppConfiguration() {
    /../
    register(ObjectMapperProvider.class);
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    /../
}
}

@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

private final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

public ObjectMapperProvider() {
    defaultObjectMapper = createDefaultMapper();
}

public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
    return defaultObjectMapper;
}

private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
    result.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    result.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    result.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    result.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    return result;
}
}
```

When I send a Json to a Post WS Method, Jackson can't convert to java object and throw

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to fr.solaire.facturation.model.MatriceComplexite
```

When i use a normal `ObjectMapper`, everything works as expected, but i don't want to replicate this code anywhere in the project.

Do you have any idea ?

```
@POST
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON) @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
public MatriceComplexite saveEntity(MatriceComplexite entityJson) {
    return matriceComplexiteRepository.save(entityJson);
}
```

I have the following error.

```
09-Dec-2015 11:46:32.369 SEVERE [557] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringApplication] in context with path [/mediation-webapp] threw exception [java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to fr.solaire.facturation.model.MatriceComplexite] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to fr.solaire.facturation.model.MatriceComplexite
    at fr.solaire.facturation.ws.impl.MatriceComplexiteServiceImpl.saveEntity(MatriceComplexiteServiceImpl.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT : 
I wrote this method to confirm if the serialization/deserialization works well.

```
@POST
@Path("/string")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Save an entity",
        notes = "Must provide an entity in Json Format",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String saveEntity(String entityJson) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new ObjectMapper().readValue(entityJson, MatriceComplexite.class));
}
```

EDIT 2 : I forgot to delete the @Produces and @Consumes on ObjectMapperProvider. It was just to test following an other subject on stackoverflow.

EDIT 3 : On my pom.xml, i have :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

EDIT 4 : I've an interface where I put the saveEntity method and it's generic. In order to simplify this post, I dont publish this interface but it looks like the main problem.

This method :

```
@POST
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON) @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
public MatriceComplexite saveEntity(MatriceComplexite entityJson) {
    return matriceComplexiteRepository.save(entityJson);
}
```

This method is inherited from a method defined in the interface and I use generic. I dont put the JAX RS annotation on the class implemented.
In the interface :

```
public interface GenericRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>{
@POST
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON) @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
T saveEntity(T entityJson);
}
```

And an other interface where i've just the following definition :

```
public interface MatriceComplexiteRepository extends GenericRepository<MatriceComplexite>{}
```

I saw this kind of warning on catalina :

**WARNING 1 argument T for saveEntity not a concrete class**

I'm going to take a look on GenericType of Jersey.

EDIT 5 : 
Yesterday, I had this log on tomcat

```
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type T from public fr.solaire.facturation.model.MatriceComplexite fr.solaire.facturation.ws.impl.MatriceComplexiteServiceImpl.saveEntity(fr.solaire.facturation.model.MatriceComplexite) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 2 of type T from public fr.solaire.facturation.model.MatriceComplexite fr.solaire.facturation.ws.impl.MatriceComplexiteServiceImpl.updateEntity(java.lang.String,fr.solaire.facturation.model.MatriceComplexite) is not resolvable
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: Afaict you did everything ok. Maybe the `MatriceComplexite` is not serializable with Jackson's `ObjectMapper`? Did you try to deserialize it 'by hand' (i.e. `new ObjectMapper().readValue(matriceAsString, MatriceComplexite.class)`)?

Comment: When i use it, it works. But don't work when i use the custom mapper. Any Idea ? For information, MatriceComplexite is a jpa @Entity.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any obvious reason why it doesn't work. The only difference I see with the `@Provider` I'm using is that mine is not annotated with `@Produces` and `@Consumes`. Apart from that, I'm using Weblogic instead of Tomcat (so you have to register your provider, but you are already doing that).

Comment: so, if i follow what you are saying, one of your configuration params (for your custom mapper) is "bad".  did you try removing config params until it works correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your help @francescoforesti! I forgot to delete Produces and Consumes but it's not this ! I added the interface Serializable on MatriceComplexite but dont work. The problem is on the deserialization and not on the serialization.

Comment: I removed allconfig parameter on the custom ObjectMapper. Any effect.

Comment: I think the generic is  the problem

Comment: There is nothing wrong with @Produces/@Consumes on the ContextResolver. It's one way narrow down the search when looking through Providers